# How do I translate x86 GCC-style C inline assembly to Rust inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, rust

I have the following inline assembly in C:

```c
unsigned long long result;
asm volatile(".byte 15;.byte 49;shlq $32,%%rdx;orq %%rdx,%%rax"
    : "=a" (result) ::  "%rdx");
return result;
```

I tried to rewrite it in Rust:

```
let result: u64;
unsafe {
    asm!(".byte 15\n\t
          .byte 49\n\t
          shlq 32, rdx\n\t
          orq  rdx, rax"
         : "=a"(result)
         :
         : "rdx"
         : "volatile"
         );
}
result
```

It doesn't recognize the `=a` constraint an it gives me an invalid operand error for `rdx` and `rax` at `shlq` and `orq` instructions. What is the proper way to rewrite the above C inline assembly in Rust?

Comment: You may be interested in noting that the inline assembly syntax is unstable, and there is discussion on its future [right now](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-inline-assembly/6443).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: That's just an `rdtsc`. Are you sure you don't have a way to access that without inline asm?

Comment: @Jester Probably, I can use [this](https://gz.github.io/rust-x86/x86/time/fn.rdtsc.html). But, still wondering about how would one translate the above C inline assembly to Rust.

Comment: One always has to even wonder how to translate C inline assembly to machine code (with all the different targets and compilers around), not even mentioning Rust. In "assembly" tagged questions the general consensus is to advice people against usage of inline assembly. If you need particular instruction, there're often intrinsics functions to use those directly in C, or you can write stand-alone assembly source which poses usually less problems than inline version (although pure C source **is portable** and more maintainable). While I'm not Rust user, I'm 100% sure this applies to Rust too.

Comment: So you are asking how to keep low quality source in low quality... while you have intrinsics for `rdtsc` available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust is built on top of LLVM, so a lot of low-level detail like this can be gleaned from what LLVM or Clang do.

1. If you want to specify a specific register, you use the register name as the constraint: `"={rax}"(result)`. Based on [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html), the `a` constraint is the "a" register.
2. Literals must be prefaced with `$$`
3. Registers must be prefaced with `%`

```
let result: u64;
unsafe {
    asm!(".byte 15
          .byte 49
          shlq $$32, %rdx
          orq  %rdx, %rax"
         : "={rax}"(result)
         :
         : "rdx"
         : "volatile"
    );
}
result
```

If I'm understanding the discussion about `rdtsc` correctly, you can also do:

```
let upper: u64;
let lower: u64;
unsafe {
    asm!("rdtsc"
         : "={rax}"(lower), 
           "={rdx}"(upper)
         :
         :
         : "volatile"
    );
}
upper << 32 | lower
```

I advise getting *out* of inline assembly as soon as it's practical.

---

The assembly of each function:

```
playground::thing1:
    #APP
    .byte   15
    .byte   49
    shlq    $32, %rdx
    orq %rdx, %rax
    #NO_APP
    retq

playground::thing2:
    #APP
    rdtsc
    #NO_APP
    shlq    $32, %rdx
    orq %rdx, %rax
    retq
```

For completeness, here is the same code using the LLVM intrinsic. This requires a *different* unstable attribute:

```
#![feature(link_llvm_intrinsics)]

extern "C" {
    #[link_name = "llvm.x86.rdtsc"]
    fn rdtsc() -> u64;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", unsafe { rdtsc() })
}
```

Sources:

- The unstable book chapter on [`asm`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/asm.html).
- The [LLVM inline assembly reference](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#inline-assembler-expressions).
- My libraries [jetscii](https://github.com/shepmaster/jetscii/blob/master/src/lib.rs) and [cupid](https://github.com/shepmaster/jetscii/blob/master/src/lib.rs).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. One question, do registers need to be prefixed with `%` also if I use the `"intel"` option?

Comment: @tinker I've never used the Intel syntax myself, so I'm not sure.

Comment: rdtsc has also some precedence: https://github.com/gz/rust-x86/blob/1e2efb6b7a0d76d9b672e09862515f5ac2541d9f/src/shared/time.rs#L17; https://github.com/ArtemGr/gstuff.rs/blob/eae4fbafff5c9e898ae762190c9a5f921a445505/gstuff.rs#L448.

Comment: @ArtemGr feels like both of those need the `volatile` keyword to avoid the optimizer returning the same value for distinct calls, no? Also, it looks like someone snuck in and moved all of your closing curly braces to the previous line :-p :-)

Comment: @ArtemGr: LLVM "knows about" `rdtsc`.  Or at least the Clang front-end supports `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc` so you don't have to (and thus shouldn't) use inline asm at all.  https://godbolt.org/g/e9a8Kk.  Does Rust expose `rdtsc` / `rdtscp` with a similar builtin / intrinsic?

Comment: @Shepmaster, thanks, fixed! https://github.com/ArtemGr/gstuff.rs/commit/f5c395dbbfcc6e1a7fff521438b385751b900a2e;  :-D

Comment: @PeterCordes, I don't see it in https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/intrinsics/index.html or in the Rust tracker.